# Print to manual feed MS Interop Word

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, office-interop

I'm trying to print a MS Word document from manual feed (in order to print to envelopes)
I found out that the Envelope.PrintOut method has a FeedSource property that suppose to help define this,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197594.aspx

but i am having a hard time to use that...
Here is a function i am using to print a document that works, if fromFeed is false (a regular print) but not if its true...
of course i tried different types of WdPaperTray values...

```
    public void PrintDocument(bool fromFeed)
    {
        this.doc = this.ap.Documents.Open(this.pathToNewFile, ReadOnly: false, Visible: false);
        //if (fromFeed)
       //     this.doc.Envelope.FeedSource = WdPaperTray.wdPrinterManualFeed;
        object copies = "1";
        object pages = "";
        object range = WdPrintOutRange.wdPrintAllDocument;
        object items = WdPrintOutItem.wdPrintDocumentContent;
        object pageType = WdPrintOutPages.wdPrintAllPages;
        object oTrue = true;
        object oFalse = false;
        object missing = System.Type.Missing;
        this.doc.Activate();
        if (fromFeed)
            this.doc.Envelope.PrintOut(missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, WdPaperTray.wdPrinterManualFeed, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
        else
            this.doc.PrintOut(ref oTrue, ref oFalse, ref range, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref items, ref copies, ref pages, ref pageType, ref oFalse, ref oTrue,
            ref missing, ref oFalse, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        this.ap.Documents.Close(SaveChanges: false, OriginalFormat: false, RouteDocument: false);
    }
```

than i found this :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.envelope.feedsource(v=office.11).aspx

and it says :
"If you use this property before an envelope has been added to the document, an error occurs"

So maybe i just need to add an envelope to the document ? but what is an envelope in a MS Word document ?

Btw I'm developing it as WPF.
and at this point the code throws this exception:object values out of range exception

Any help will be most welcomed.